# How to kill setInterval() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this finction:

```
 var msec = 100;
   setInterval(function () {
            if (childNodeDocument.readyState == "complete") {
                parent.parent.mapFrame.hideModal;
                alert("complete");
                clearInterval();
            }
        }, msec);
```

when this condition is satisfied:

```
childNodeDocument.readyState == "complete"
```

I want to stop executing setInterval().

But the way I am doing above not working.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the id that is returned by `setTimeout` and use that to cancel it...

```
var msec = 100;
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        if (childNodeDocument.readyState == "complete") {
            parent.parent.mapFrame.hideModal;
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            alert("complete");
        }
    }, msec);
```

Also, note that I put it before your `alert`

Answer (score 1):

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
//  ^^^^^^^^
    if (childNodeDocument.readyState == "complete") {
        parent.parent.mapFrame.hideModal;
        clearInterval(interval);
        //            ^^^^^^^^
        alert("complete");
    }
}, msec);
```